# react native giving localstorage getItem not a function error

Tags: react-native

I was trying to use the Async Storage official react native API. The code in my react native looks like this:

```
export function get(key) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    AsyncStorage.getItem(key, (err, val) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
      } else {
        if (val === null) {
          reject('key_not_found')
        } else {
          var parsedVal = JSON.parse(val)
          console.log('got value from storage =>', parsedVal);
          resolve(parsedVal)
        }
      }
    })
  });
}
```

I worked for a week without any problem, but recently it starts to give this error

[image]

The logger output from remote JS debugger looks like this

[image]

I didn't change any of the `npm modules` except that I installed `moment.js` using `npm install --save moment` Any idea what might be happening here?

## UPDATE:

The places where I used this exported function are:

```
//This one is inside the same file so I just use get without module name
export function retrieveCredential() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    get('credential')
    .then((val) => {
      resolve(val)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
      reject(err)
    })
  });
}

//this function is also exported
export function autoLogin() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    LocalStorage.retrieveCredential()
    .then((credential) => {
      loginWithEmail (credential.email, credential.password, false)
      .then(() => {
        resolve()
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        reject(err)
      })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
      reject(err)
    })
  });
}

//This is finally used in one of the component
Authentication.autoLogin()
    .then(() => { ... })
    .catch(() => { ... })
```

## Project search for localstorage.getItem result:

[image]

Comment: As I understood you declared module with this function. Please, show code where you use this module.

Comment: @KonstantinYakushin I just added where I used this module.

Comment: I still don't see construction of this kind `k.localStorage.getItem`. Try  to find such place in your code.

Comment: @KonstantinYakushin is there a way to backtrace exception manager? I don't get this error when there is no saved credential so the only source I know is from the process getting credential from Async Storage (just a matter of where exactly). Also, I don't understand how comes this error is not caught by any of the catch statement. What is this error type indicating exactly?

Comment: Try to use debugger. Set breakpoint and debug code.

Comment: Can you please search for localStorage.getItem inside your whole project excluding node_modules.

Comment: @AkshayRao I just added the search into the post. The strange thing is that it doesn't appear in any part of my project.